# TCP/IP communication between BeagleBone Black and PC

Tags: c++, tcp, beagleboneblack

I am creating a local network between my BeagleBone Black and my PC. Both devices are connected through ethernet network. My BleagleBone has IP address = "192.168.1.15" and my computer has IP address = "192.168.1.20". I am connected to the BeagleBone through ssh connection in order to pass all the necessary files to it.

On the other hand, the BleagleBone is the Client in this communication because it will send data strings to muy PC (the server).

I am using the following code:

*server.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

#define PORT 20001
#define SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE  1024

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     // create a socket
     // socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
     printf("\nHola1");
     sockfd =  socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     printf("\nHola2");
     if (sockfd < 0){
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     }
     printf("\nHola3");

     // clear address structure
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

     portno = atoi(argv[1]);

     /* setup the host_addr structure for use in bind call */
     // server byte order
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

     // automatically be filled with current host's IP address
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

     // convert short integer value for port must be converted into network byte order
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

     // bind(int fd, struct sockaddr *local_addr, socklen_t addr_length)
     // bind() passes file descriptor, the address structure,
     // and the length of the address structure
     // This bind() call will bind  the socket to the current IP address on port, portno
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
              error("ERROR on binding");

     // This listen() call tells the socket to listen to the incoming connections.
     // The listen() function places all incoming connection into a backlog queue
     // until accept() call accepts the connection.
     // Here, we set the maximum size for the backlog queue to 5.
     listen(sockfd,5);

     // The accept() call actually accepts an incoming connection
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

     // This accept() function will write the connecting client's address info
     // into the the address structure and the size of that structure is clilen.
     // The accept() returns a new socket file descriptor for the accepted connection.
     // So, the original socket file descriptor can continue to be used
     // for accepting new connections while the new socker file descriptor is used for
     // communicating with the connected client.
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0)
          error("ERROR on accept");

     printf("server: got connection from %s port %d\n",inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port));


     // This send() function sends the 13 bytes of the string to the new socket
     send(newsockfd, "Hello, world!\n", 13, 0);

     bzero(buffer,256);

     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);

     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0;
}
```

*client.cpp*

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0)
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
    if (n < 0)
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

First I run the server executable on my PC by the following command `./Server 20001`
And then I run the Client in the BleagleBone by `./Client 192.168.1.20 20001`

What I obtain on the BeagleBone is:
`ERROR connecting: connection refused`

I do not understand why it does not work.

NOTE: when I assign a port it does not bind. It does not give an error just stop working there.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++? It looks like C to me.

Comment: @JesperJuhl it is a C/C++ eclipse project

Comment: There is no such language "C/C++". The two languages C and C++ are *very* different and you seem to be writing code in the former but tagging your question with the latter.

Comment: @JesperJuhl anyway I think that it is not the most important thing in my question

Comment: Maybe not. But if you *are* writing C but get a C++ answer due to the tag, then you will end up with code which your C compiler may not accept. So, it's important to get language tags right so that people answering will actually be providing you with something you *can* use. Just trying to help you here.. :-)

Comment: have you tried to use `nc` to debug which side (client or server) doesn't work?

Comment: What OS are you running on your PC? Does it have a firewall blocking your server from access to the network? Does it block your client from connecting?

Comment: @jwdonahue I am running the server in a virtual machine with OS debian 9.4 and the client on the beagle bone with OS 8.7 jessie. I have turned off the windows firewall so I think that it is not the problem.